# EGit + Google Code Hosting

Tags: git, google-code

I'd like to make a Git repo on code.google.com/hosting instead of github. Currently I'm having problem setting this up.

I find SVN + Google Hosting easy to start: Make a new repo, make a new project on eclipse, use subclipse to make an initial commit of that project to the google repo.

How do I setup a git repo with Google? I'm hoping for a noob explanation from head to toe kinda stuff.

If you know of a tutorial you could point me to, that'd be fine as well. I found a Vogella tutorial however that only showed how'd to clone an exist repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your google code project page, go to Administer -> Source, and then click the button to switch to Git.

Then go to Source -> Checkout to get the repository URL.

Then, I would go into Eclipse and start a new project.  After creating the project, commit it to a local git repository.

Then add the google code repository as a new remote to your the local git repository and then you can push from the local to the remote.

Comment: so currently what i did was: right click on project and push to a remote...but after i entered my info, the remote repo (google repo) dosent show up any more...i have to reenter the info again...is there a way to save it?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with EGit (I usually use the command line), but I it sounds like you did a direct push without adding a remote.  Maybe try "Team > Remote > Configure push to upstream..." to get the remote added permanently, and then use "push to upstream" instead of "push to remote".  The .git/config file should have the remote information if it's set up correctly.